# Text rotation from centre not accurate

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to rotate some text around its centre point, however because of the letter spacing in different fonts, I can't get it to be exact.

The change is even more drastic when I'm using other custom fonts. The purple text in the example is the accurate version. The red one is not.

I have to replace existing text nodes in an SVG applying any changes made by a user (such as rotations and changes in x,y).

The following matrix transform is taken from  nodes I'm replacing based on a users changes.

```
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 77.9443 50.3945)"></g>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6cu01c4o/

From my understanding I'm using the proper values to calculate the rotate offsets, so I'm a little confused as to what is happening here.

Comment: How did you calculate the center points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making life very difficult for yourself here.

If you want text to rotate around its central point, a good first step would be to have the text centred on that point in the first place.

Use `text-anchor="middle"` to centre the text horizontally, and `dominant-baseline="central"` to centre it vertically. (Actually, the latter may not give perfect results every time, depending on the particular typeface you're using, but in most cases it's perfectly adequate.)

Simply guessing the centre coordinates of a block of left-justified text is inevitably going to land you in trouble, because different clients will have a different set of installed fonts, and different defaults for `serif`, `sans-serif`, etc.

```html
<svg width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <g font-size="29">
    <g transform="translate(50 50)" font-family="sans-serif">
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">TEST</text>
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(90)">TEST</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(150 50)" font-family="serif">
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">TEST</text>
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(90)">TEST</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(250 50)" font-family="monospace">
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">TEST</text>
      <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(90)">TEST</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```